# How to get variable for category_ID in this code

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

**PHP:**

```
<?php
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","bookofexperiences");
    $sql2 ="SELECT Category_Title FROM category WHERE Category_ID=5";
    $query = mysqli_query($con, $sql2);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
    $scategory = $row['Category_Title'];

    echo("<h3>". $scategory. "<h3/>");
    echo("<hr><br>");
?>
```

I want get different `Category_ID` when pressing different button. Now I'm using each button for different page which had only changed `Category_ID`. when I press a button, I got "Category_ID=5" and their content. When I press a another button, I got "Category_ID=6" and their content. But Now I used two different pages for this work. I want fix this one for one page.  please help me how to fix this problem

Comment: Do you have problem in pagination?

Answer (score 1):

make the category id part of the url, then use $_GET to pull it into your query. So your url would be your domain.com/index.php?category=5

then you code would change to:

```
$sql2 = "SELECT Category_Title FROM category WHERE Category_ID='$_GET[category]'";
```

Comment: Look out for the SQL injection monster, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1.